# How to rearange commits in few independed branches in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I need to rearrange a "linear structure"

```
temp       -C1-C2-C3-C4-C5-C6-C7-C8-C9-C10
         /
master -C0
```

to "fork-like structure".

```
branch-1   -C1-C2-C3-C4-C5
         /
master -C0
         \
branch-2   -C6-C7-C8-C9-C10
```

Example: Let's start from one branch (let's name it **temp**), derived from the **master**, and then let's put few commits - **C1** .. **C10**. 
Instead of this I'd like to have two branches based on master (one per feature). I can create these two branches by referring the commit before **C1**. Than, how to reshuffle (merge?) all commits in a way to get commits from **C1** to **C5** in **branch-1** (derived from **master**) and branches from **C6** to **C10** in **branch-2** also derived from **master**? As result in the log of **branch-2** I expect to have **C0**, **C6..C10** (where **C0** is the last commit in the **master** branch).

Probably the **branch-1** can be retrieved by renaming **temp** and doing

```
git reset --hard  HEAD~5 #or 4 (?)
```

But for the **branch-2** how to remove **C1..C5** and keep the rest?

EDIT: Here is the test script that can be used to reproduce the case:

```
#!/bin/bash

## file names
file1='file1'
file2='file2'

## clean-up for fresh start
if [ -d .git ] 
then
    rm -rf .git
fi
## create files
echo start1 > $file1
echo start2 > $file2

## start the repository creation 
git init
git add $file1 $file2
git commit -am 'C0'

## linear branch
git checkout -b temp

## implement features 1 & 2 in files 1 & 2
for i in {1..10}
do
    if [ $i -le 5 ]
    then
    file=$file1
    else
    file=$file2
    fi
    msg='line '$i
    echo $msg >> $file
    git commit -m "C$i" $file
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git branch branch-1 C5
git branch -m temp branch-2
git rebase --onto C0 branch-1 branch-2
```